# SQL query to join multiple tables based upon separate query result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the right SQL query to join multiple tables together based upon a separate query..

I query the 'Titles' table to get the 'TitleId' - I then need to query 'Titles_Hardware' and 'Titles_Software' to match the 'Title Id' to the 'Hardware ID'/'Software Id'.

I then need to take those 'Hardware Ids' and 'Software Ids' to query the 'Hardware' and 'Software' tables to grab the friendly names of the Hardware and Software that particular user needs.

I have tried subqueries/cross join and many other queries I found on this site - none seem to give me what I need.. any suggestions would be absolutely amazing!

Outline of the database (tables are shown in italics)..

[image]

Comment: Pls also see the following guidance to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sample data would be helpful and desired output along with anything you have tried.  This seems fairly straight forward if we had a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a simple multi-level join

```
SELECT TitleName, HardwareName, SoftwareName
FROM Titles
INNER JOIN Titles_Hardware
ON Titles.TitleId = Titles_Hardware.TitleId
INNER JOIN Titles_Software
ON Titles.TitleId = Titles_Software.TitleId
INNER JOIN Hardware
ON Hardware.HardwareId = Titles_Hardware.HardwareId
INNER JOIN Software
ON Software.SoftwareId = Titles_Software.SoftwareId
WHERE Titles.TitleId = {something}
```

Comment: Steve - this works beautifully!   [The only 'issue' now is that I receive duplicates](https://imgur.com/ZR34t2v) - any idea how to remove those?

Comment: What duplicates? Each row in the screenshot is unique, there are no duplicates... Also please include this image in your question, so that when imgur deletes it everything still makes sense here...

Comment: @MattOestreich to me thats not duplicate. There are multiple different hardware/software combinations that are having the same title

Comment: @Steve - my fault - Basically, all I need is the Title (just one 'Senior Director'), the list of HardwareNames (Dell Latitude 7490, Dock, Dual Display, Keyboard & Mouse), and the list of SoftwareNames (Office 365, Adobe, Kaluza, FlowJo).. is this even possible with SQL?

Comment: @MattOestreich well you always get a table back whenever you query data. So if you want one string + 2 list you would have to perform 3 queries or you would have to filter out data by yourself

Comment: @Steve - I cannot thank you enough!  Your query speeds things up a ton - I can remove the "duplicates" via C# after the query is returned.

Comment: @MattOestreich no problem and welcome to the sql world

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you want, but it's not clear what you mean by "join multiple tables together based upon a separate query..". Here I just treated everything as tables.

```
SELECT t.TitleName, t.TitleId, h.HardwareName, s.SoftwareName
FROM Titles t
INNER JOIN Title_Hardware th ON th.TitleId = t.TitleId
INNER JOIN Hardware h ON h.HardwareId = th.HardwareId
INNER JOIN Title_Software ts ON ts.TitleId = t.TitleId
INNER JOIN Software s ON s.SoftwareId = ts.SoftwareId
WHERE t.TitleId = 'bleh'
```

### EDIT

From the comments, you need three queries to get what you want:

```
SELECT t.TitleName
FROM Titles t
WHERE t.TitleId = 'bleh'

SELECT h.HardwareName
FROM Titles t
INNER JOIN Title_Hardware th ON th.TitleId = t.TitleId
INNER JOIN Hardware h ON h.HardwareId = th.HardwareId
WHERE t.TitleId = 'bleh'

SELECT s.SoftwareName
FROM Titles t
INNER JOIN Title_Software ts ON ts.TitleId = t.TitleId
INNER JOIN Software s ON s.SoftwareId = ts.SoftwareId
WHERE t.TitleId = 'bleh'
```

Comment: Sorry - your answer satisfies my request (I have a query at the end, in place of 'bleh' - that is what I meant by based off of a separate query, that's my fault).. The only issue now is that the query you so generously provided, gives me duplicates :( Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Replace `SELECT` by `SELECT DISTINCT`? I'm not sure where the duplicates could come from, unless you mean your query returns multiple TitleIds... This is why it really helps to give the full story when writing your question, instead of letting the reader decide what it is you want...

Comment: After seeing the screenshot of the "duplicates", they clearly are not duplicates...

Comment: I think it should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, in case a title may have hardware title, but not software title, etc.

Comment: That kind of depends on what the OP wants though, and it's not stated one way or the other...

Comment: My fault - basically, all I need is the Title (just one 'Senior Director'), the list of HardwareNames (Dell Latitude 7490, Dock, Dual Display, Keyboard & Mouse), and the list of SoftwareNames (Office 365, Adobe, Kaluza, FlowJo).. is this even possible with SQL?

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey - I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` before posting the screenshot - no dice.

Comment: You would need three queries to do what you want... Think about it, one row is one "unit". Multiple fields in a row have a relation to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a series of INNER JOINs to achieve your goal, like :

```
select 
    t.titleName,
    h.hardwareName,
    s.softwareName
from titles t
inner join titles_hardware th on th.titleId = t.titleId
inner join hardware h on h.hardwareId = th.hardwareId
inner join titles_sotfware ts on ts.titleId = t.titleId
inner join software s on s.softwareId = ts.softwareId
where t.titleId = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a UNION could work for you

```
DECLARE @TitleName VARCHAR(100) = 'The Boss Lady';

SELECT hard.HardwareName AS Name, 'hard' as TitleType, tit.TitleName
FROM Titles tit
JOIN Titles_Hardware tithard ON tithard.TitleId = tit.TitleId
JOIN Hardware hard ON hard.HardwareId = tithard.HardwareId
WHERE tit.TitleName = @TitleName

UNION ALL

SELECT soft.SoftwareName, 'soft', tit.TitleName
FROM Titles tit
JOIN Titles_Software titsoft ON titsoft.TitleId = tit.TitleId
JOIN Software soft ON soft.SoftwareId = titsoft.SoftwareId
WHERE tit.TitleName = @TitleName
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much. I believe this is what I need - I love how you define the 'TitleType' - that is perfect!

Comment: Well, it can just be a number or a letter.  But you get the point. Btw, if you're doing it via a variable (see update) then it's best if its the same datatype & size as for the TitleName column.